# How can i shorten this javascript if statement ? ( if 1 , if 2 )

Tags: javascript

I am creating a site that extracts data from an api. I want to create an if else statement that changes the html based on if the result is 0,1,2,4. Can i fit this into one statement rather than having 4 separate statements?

```
if(data.results.indexOf(element) === 0){
      result0.style.display = "block"
      result0.innerHTML =
      `${element.original_title}`
    } else if (data.results.indexOf(element) === 1){
      result1.style.display = "block"
      result1.innerHTML =
      `${element.original_title}`
  } else if (data.results.indexOf(element) === 2){
    result2.style.display = "block"
    result2.innerHTML =
    `${element.original_title}`
  } else if (data.results.indexOf(element) === 3){
    result3.style.display = "block"
    result3.innerHTML =
    `${element.original_title}`
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can index an array:

```js
const ele = [result0, result1, result2, result3][data.results.indexOf(element)];
ele.style.display = "block";
ele.innerHTML = element.original_title;
```

Comment: Or store `const results = [result0, result1, result2, result3];` and reference `results` each time instead of making a temporary array.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get flamed for this, but you can also do it this way:

```
let res = eval(`result${data.results.indexOf(element)}`);
res.style.display = "block"
res.innerHTML = `${element.original_title}`
```

However, as pointed out, it would be much better to put all the elements into a numbered array as opposed to trying to textually guess their variable names.

Comment: This will work - although it's a sign that an array of `results` should be used instead of `result1`, `result2`...